# What does `git rebase --fork-point master` mean?

Tags: git

My use case is **changing my commits** in a feature branch before I publish it, e.g., reword commit messages, squash some commits, etc. **I do not want to move the commits to a new base.**

For this, I usually do something like this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

where the number "4" is the result of manually counting the commits in my feature branch.

I was wondering if Git has a command like **"start interactive rebase for all commits in my feature branch but don't move then to a newer `master` – just stay where you are"**. I found the `--fork-point` option of `git rebase` and tried this:

```
git rebase -i --fork-point master
```

However, this doesn't have any noticeable effect and behaves the same as `git rebase -i master`.

Instead, this does what I need:

```
git rebase -i $(git merge-base --fork-point master)
```

I read the docs of `--fork-point` in `git rebase` docs but don't quite understand why it didn't lead to my expected result. Can someone explain it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't lead to your expected result because `--fork-point` has nothing to do with deciding the base for the new commits[1].

So the default is to base the new commits at the upstream (`master` in this case), and `--fork-point` doesn't affect that.

(For reference, what `--fork-point` does is, it uses the reflogs to refine the calculation that "guesses" what commits should be rewritten.  This is not always - or, in my experience, even *often* - very useful.)

Your two options are to use the merge base as the upstream - as you describe - or use the `--onto` option to explicitly set the new base (in this case, setting it to match the original base).

---

[1] - remember that even though conceptually you're editing commits, really rebase always writes new commits - except when it does nothing.  So when it 'edits' a commit, it really creates new commits that are similar to old commits, but edited.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the simpler invocation below to do what you need.

```
git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD master)
```

The documentation for [`git merge-base --fork-point`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion_on_fork_point_mode) shows that the option can highly useful but in the context of a complicated history. Your question does not indicate that you have been doing a lot of history rewriting, so `--fork-point` may be overkill for your case.

> ### Discussion on fork-point mode
>
> After working on the topic branch created with
>
> ```
> git switch -c topic origin/master
> ```
>
> the history of remote-tracking branch `origin/master`
>   may have been rewound and rebuilt, leading to a history of this shape:
>
> ```
>                  o---B2
>                 /
> ---o---o---B1--o---o---o---B (origin/master)
>         \
>          B0
>           \
>            D0---D1---D (topic)
> ```
>
> where `origin/master` used to point at commits *B0*, *B1*, *B2* and
>   now it points at *B*, and your topic branch was started on top of it
>   back when `origin/master` was at *B0*, and you built three commits,
>   *D0*, *D1*, and *D*, on top of it. Imagine that you now want to rebase the work you did on the topic on top of the updated `origin/master`.
>
> In such a case, `git merge-base origin/master topic` would return the
>   parent of *B0* in the above picture, but `B0^..D` is not the range of
>   commits you would want to replay on top of *B* (it includes *B0*,
>   which is not what you wrote; it is a commit the other side discarded
>   when it moved its tip from *B0* to *B1*).
>
> `git merge-base --fork-point origin/master topic` is designed to help in such a case. It takes not only B but also B0, B1, and B2 (i.e. old tips of the remote-tracking branches your repository’s reflog knows about) into account to see on which commit your topic branch was built and finds B0, allowing you to replay only the commits on your topic, excluding the commits the other side later discarded.

The [`git rebase --fork-point` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---fork-point) makes the connection between `git rebase --fork-point` and `git merge-base --fork-point`.

> When `--fork-point` is active, *forkpoint* will be used instead of
>   *upstream* to calculate the set of commits to rebase, where *forkpoint* is the result of
>
> ```
> git merge-base --fork-point <upstream> <branch>
> ```
>
> command. (See [`git-merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion_on_fork_point_mode).) …

Comment: Thanks, the "Discussion on fork-point mode" section explains it nicely. I didn't appreciate what it does by just reading the `git rebase` docs.

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.24 [will introduce a new option](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f21f8f5d35b09ecdd1a0112f114436fd2eda7df2/Documentation/RelNotes/2.24.0.txt#L60-L63), `--keep-base`:

> "git rebase --keep-base " tries to find the original base
>     of the topic being rebased and rebase on top of that same base,
>     which is useful when running the "git rebase -i" (and its limited
>     variant "git rebase -x").

Sounds like it might be the solution to the use case in the OP but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe these might be what you're looking for:

```
# uses "graph" to determine topological "fork point"
❯ git rebase --interactive --no-fork-point UPSTREAMREFNAME FEATURE --keep-base
```

```
# uses reflog to determine historical "fork point"
❯ git rebase --interactive --fork-point UPSTREAMREFNAME FEATURE --keep-base
```

> They can be simplified to:
>
> ```
> [HEAD -> feature] ❯ git rebase -i UPSTREAMREFNAME
> ```
>
> ```
> [HEAD -> feature] ❯ git rebase -i --fork-point UPSTREAMREFNAME
> ```

Elaboration:

- `UPSTREAMREFNAME FEATURE` are used to compute the commit range that is to be rebased.

  - if `--fork-point` is specified, the commit range produced is equivalent to `$(git merge-base --fork-point UPSTREAMREFNAME FEATURE)..FEATURE`. the "fork point" is determined based on the reflog, i.e along the lifespan of `UPSTREAMREFNAME`, at which exact hash was the most recent call/command made by `FEATURE` to branch-off-of/fork-from `UPSTREAMREFNAME` branch reference.

    - the commit range produced represents: all the created ancestor commits of `FEATURE` all the way back [in time] to where [in the reflog] the branch was forked from the specified mainline/upstream branch `UPSTREAMREFNAME`.
  - if `--no-fork-point` is specified, the commit range produced is equivalent to `UPSTREAMREFNAME..FEATURE`. the "fork point" is determined based on the topology (arrangement) of the history graph. this means that the "fork point" will be the earliest commit that `UPSTREAMREFNAME` and `FEATURE` both share, i.e the earliest point where they intersect in the graph.

    - the commit range produced represents: all commits reachable from `FEATURE` [i.e walking the history graph], excluding those reachable from `UPSTREAMREFNAME`.
  - Important: if `FEATURE` is omitted, it will default to `HEAD`, which means, if you are checked out [anywhere] on your feature branch, you don't have to specify `FEATURE` and it will work fine, else you must specify it or you might end up with a result you did not expect.
  - `UPSTREAMREFNAME`, a.k.a `<upstream>` in the `git-rebase(1)` documentation, must be the name of a reference (e.g. branch, tag)
  - `FEATURE`, a.k.a `<branch>` or `topic` in the `git-rebase(1)` documentation, is technically a "commit-ish" parameter, which means it can be anything (any notation) that resolves to a commit object name (hash id).
- `--keep-base` specifies the commit base on top of which the [recreated] commit range will be placed/based.

  - the commit base is computed to be the merge base of `UPSTREAMREFNAME` and `FEATURE`, i.e is equivalent to `--onto $(git merge-base UPSTREAMREFNAME FEATURE)`

---

References:

- `git-rebase(1)`
- `git-merge-base(1)`: discusses [plumbing] command that can find the merge base of two or more commits, defines and illustrates "fork point", and more.
- `gitrevisions(7)`: discusses at length regarding "commit-ish" notations.
- `git-rev-parse(1)`: discusses [plumbing] command that can resolve notations to object names, and more.