# Pull with rebase up to a specific commit

Tags: git, rebase

This is a variation on an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462683/git-pull-till-a-particular-commit) with a rebase twist.

I want to do a `git pull --rebase` but only till a specific commit.  This is not pulling a specific commit, this is pulling **upto** a specific commit.  The remote master looks like the following.

`A<-B<-C<-D<-E<-F<-HEAD (Remote master HEAD)`

Suppose my local feature branch HEAD points to G which points to D:

`A<-B<-C<-D<-G<-HEAD (Current local feature branch HEAD).`

I want to pull up to E with a rebase so that my branch ends up looking like:

`A<-B<-C<-D<-E<-G<-HEAD (local feature branch end goal).`

However, this is just a special case.  I want to pick any eligible commit hash, not just the second to last one as in the example above.

Naturally, I would like the hash for commit E to match remote master at the end of the operation.  I belabor that point because certain types of interactive rebase editing would cause that property to disappear.

What should I do?

Comment: In the first 2 diagrams you said `A<-B<-D` and then `A<-B<-C<-D`. Have you simply forgotten `C`? Or do you really mean this? Because for the 2nd case your goal to preserve IDs for `D` and `E` cannot be fulfilled: once `D` is rebased on top of `C` its ID is changed.

Comment: I accidentally edited away C.  Fixed now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the changes from the remote:

```
git fetch origin
```

Rebase onto the remote version of master, ignoring some number of commits:

```
git rebase origin/master~<n>
```

where `<n>` is the number of commits from the tip of `master` you want to ignore.

If you have the id of the commit you want to rebase onto, you can use that instead:

```
git rebase <commit-id>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

[Calum Halpin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019258/1256452) is correct: you must break your `git pull` into its two separate constituent commands: `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`.  It probably deserves more explanation though.

#### Long

Let me redraw your graphs a bit to make them look (I think anyway) a bit clearer.  I'm going to replace the internal backwards-pointing arrows with simpler connecting dashes, though, because I need to draw some "arrows" that point up-and-left or down-and-left, and this doesn't work very well here.  (I have arrow-drawing characters on my system that don't always show in on other Web browsers on other systems.)

On the remote we have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
```

That is, there is a chain of commits, with some big ugly hash IDs that we've replaced with letters for convenience, that ends at commit `F`.  *Their* Git's name `master` contains the hash ID of commit `F`.  (The name `master` may or may not be the current branch on the remote: it does not matter for our purposes, so there is no need for us to draw in the special name `HEAD` here.)

Meanwhile we have this locally:

```
A--B--C--D--G   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

i.e., we and they share commits `A` through `D`, including their linkage, and our Git's name `feature` contains the hash ID of commit `G` which points back to `D`.

> I want to pull up to E with a rebase so that my branch ends up looking like:
>
> ```
> A--B--C--D--E--G   <-- feature (HEAD)
> ```
>
> However, this is just a special case. I want to pick any eligible commit hash, not just the second to last one as in the example above.

What you need to do is *avoid* the `git pull` command.

What `git pull` does is run *two* more-basic Git commands: first `git fetch`, then a second command of your choice.  The second command is usually `git merge` but if you use `--rebase`, or various other configuration methods, you can have it run `git rebase` instead.  What you *cannot* do is pass the right arguments *to* `git rebase`, where by "right arguments" I mean the ones that solve the problem in question.

Let's run `git fetch` first.  This has our Git call up their Git.  Their Git tells our Git about its various branch and tag and other such names, including the fact that their `master` identifies commit `F`.  Our Git checks out repository and discovers that we *don't* have commit `F`, so our Git asks to get it.  Their Git then offers commit `E` as well—the sender *has* to offer everything we need, and we'll need `E` to hold `F`—and our Git asks for that too.  They offer `D`, but we already have that, so we tell them to stop there.

They now build a so-called *thin pack* that contains what we need to add commits `E` and `F` to our repository.  This is the "counting objects and "compressing objects" stuff you see when you run `git fetch`, or any command that runs `git fetch`.  They send us the thin pack; our Git takes that thin pack and fixes it up so that it's usable, and now we have the commits they had, that we didn't, that we need to finish `git fetch`-ing.

If there's nothing else we need, our Git says *'kthanksbye* to their Git and proceeds to update our *remote-tracking names*.  We have, in our Git, names `origin/master` and so on: these are where *our* Git remembers what *their* Git said *their* hash IDs were, for *their* branch names, the last time we talked with them.  As long as we have the commits that *their* branches remember, our Git can update our remote-tracking names accordingly, so it does.  This leaves us with:

```
A--B--C--D--G   <-- feature (HEAD)
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
```

(There's that up-and-left pointing arrow, going from `E` to `D`, drawn without using arrow characters.)

We're now ready to run `git rebase`.

#### If we just ran `git rebase` like `git pull` does

If we ran `git rebase origin/master`—`git pull` actually uses `git rebase  but this does the same thing—Git would:

- list out commits reachable from our current `HEAD`: `G`, `D`, `C`, and so on;
- list out commits reachable from `origin/master`: `F`, `E`, `D`, `C`, and so on;
- remove from the first list anything in the second list;
- remove any additional commits that should not be copied;<sup>1</sup>
- put the list in the right order (reversed from Git's internal backwards order); and
- begin copying those commits, one by one, as if by `git cherry-pick`.<sup>2</sup>

Since this list consists only of commit `G`, that's the one commit we'll copy.  But: *Where does this copy go?*

A regular `git rebase` places the copy, or if there are multiple commits to copy, copies plural, *right after the commit named on the command line*.  Since `git rebase` as run by `git pull` names commit `F`—the commit to which our `origin/master` points, after `git fetch` updated our `origin/master` to match `origin`'s `master`—we'll get:

```
A--B--C--D--G
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
               \
                G'
```

as the result.  (I've removed some of the names because for this moment, the names aren't really interesting, and `git rebase` will be fiddling with them too; we just haven't drawn that part yet.)

Had there been more commits, e.g., `G-H-I`, we would end up with `G'-H'-I'` on the bottom row here.  In all cases, the *original* commits, pre-copying, remain.  At this point, `git rebase` finishes its work by *moving the name* to which our `HEAD` is attached to point to the final copied commit:<sup>3</sup>

```
A--B--C--D--G   [was `feature`, now abandoned]
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
               \
                G'   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Depending on argument to `git rebase`, this normally includes *all merge commits*, plus any commits for which `git patch-id` computes identical patch IDs.  The patch-ID computation part is a little tricky to describe: it involves using `git rev-list --left-right` with the symmetric difference triple-dot operator.  For many rebases, neither of these matters, which is why I merely have this footnote.

<sup>2</sup>Some types of `git rebase` literally run `git cherry-pick`.  Others—including the default one and the one run by `git pull`—use a faster but cheesier mechanism involving `git format-patch` and `git am` that can miss rename operations.  You can force rebase to use the slower but more-accurate cherry-pick method by adding `-m`, or doing an interactive rebase, or adding other options.  There's rarely any real need for this though.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, Git ran each of the copying operations with a *detached HEAD*, in which `HEAD` points directly to the copy once the copy is made.  But of course `git rebase` *starts* by saving the fact of the attachment—the fact that `HEAD` was attached to `feature`—so that when the rebase finishes, Git knows to (1) move `feature` and (2) re-attach `HEAD`.

---

#### What you want to do instead: specify where the copies go

If you run `git rebase` yourself, *you* get to pick the argument that `git rebase` calls *upstream*.  When `git pull` does it, it gives `git rebase` the hash ID to which your updated `origin/master` points.  If you do it with:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

you give it the name `origin/master`, which it resolves to that same hash ID, and you get the result we saw.

But if you *do* run this manually, *you* can put in the hash ID, or anything else that names the commit you want.  This tells `git rebase` *where the copies go*.

In this case, then, if you name commit `E` by any means–raw hash ID, or `origin/master^`, or `origin/master~` will al work—your `git rebase` will copy `G` to a `G'` that comes after `E`:

```
A--B--C--D--G   [was `feature`, now abandoned]
          \
           E--F   <-- origin/master
            \
             G'   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

and you get the desired result.

#### There is *one more* control knob available to you now too

When you run `git rebase` by hand, instead of having `git pull` do it for you, you get one more option.  Look again at the bullet-point list of steps above, where `git rebase` figures out which commits to copy.  If you run:

```
git rebase <upstream>
```

Git lists out commits as if by:<sup>4</sup>

```
git log <upstream>..HEAD
```

(as shown in [the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase); add `--fork-point` as needed, and see footnote 4).

It then copies the listed commits, using *`upstream`* as the target for the copying.  But what if you have, e.g.:

```
...--B--C--D--E--F   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \
          G--H--I   <-- origin/master
```

where commit `D` was an emergency hack fix you made so that could write commits `E` and `F`, and meanwhile someone wrote the real fix as commit `G`, `H`, and/or `I`?

While `git rebase` tries to be smart about omitting commits that are already in the upstream—e.g., if commit `G` matches commit `D`, `git rebase` knows not to copy `D`—this does not work in all cases.  In particular, it usually *won't* work to drop an emergency "fix" that actually just disabled or eliminated a feature, rather than really fixing the bug in the feature.

You could use `git rebase -i` to handle this, but long before `git rebase -i`, there was `git rebase --onto`.  With `--onto`, you get to *split off* the target-selection from the upstream-limiting argument.

That is, in this diagram, what we want as our result is to copy *only* commits `E` and `F`, leaving `D`—our emergency fix that isn't really right—behind.  To tell Git this, we use `git rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master <hash-of-D>
```

or:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master branch~2
```

Our *`upstream`* argument now names commit `D`.  That's the commit *not* to copy (nor any of the earlier commits).

If we ran a `git rebase` like this but without the `--onto` argument, Git (a) would not copy `D` but then (b) would place the copies of `E` and `F` right after `D`.  The result is what we *don't* want (draw it to see).  But when we add `--onto origin/master`, that tells rebase to put the copies after commit `I`.  The result is:

```
...--B--C--D--E--F   [abandoned]
         \
          G--H--I   <-- origin/master
                 \
                  E'-F'  <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Commits `D-E-F` are all dropped, in favor of the new and improved `E'-F'` commits.  We don't have to manually drop `D` as our `git rebase` arguments did that for us.  Redrawing the chain with the abandoned commits invisible gives us:

```
...--B--C--G--H--I   <-- origin/master
                  \
                   E'-F'  <-- branch (HEAD)
```

and if no one but us ever knew about commits `E` and `F`, we can just *pretend* that we only wrote the new copies, rather than the originals: no one (except us) will ever know.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>Try this yourself!  You'll get a list of hash IDs, one per line.  They come out in Git's preferred order though—backwards—which isn't suitable for `git rebase`, and they *don't* omit the commits that `git rebase` will omit.  Still, rebase actually *does* use `git rev-list` internally, it's just that it adds a lot of options: `--no-merges` to drop merges commits, and `--topo-order --reverse` to get the right order.  Last, there is a bit of magic to exclude commits that have the same patch-IDs as commits on the upstream side, as noted in footnote 1.  This involves using the three-dot syntax, `<upstream>...HEAD`, and adding `--right-only --cherry-pick`.  When rebase was a shell script, this was easy to find; now that it has been rewritten in C code, it's much harder to figure out.

When the fork-point option is in effect, the `<upstream>` parameter here gets replaced by the result of `git merge-base --fork-point`, which uses your `origin/master` reflog to guess if some commits should be omitted.  See, e.g., [Revision selection in git using fork-point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58938650/1256452) and [What does `git rebase --fork-point master` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57822546/1256452).

I'm still somewhat unconvinced that fork-point mode is the right default (it can be surprising sometimes) and am not yet sure whether the new Git 2.24 `--keep-base` option uses the fork-point type merge base, or the real merge base.  But do note that if you rebase using anything that is not a *name*—e.g., if your rebase *`upstream`* argument is a hash ID—that disables fork-point mode, as the fork-point base is computed by scanning a reflog, and only *names* have reflogs.

<sup>5</sup>And we'll probably forget.  Who can remember raw hash IDs?

---

#### Conclusions

- Git is really all about *commits*.  Branch names, when you use them—and when Git uses them—are just there to help you find the *last* commit in some branch.  Commits are frozen forever, and (mostly) permanent (if you cannot *find* them, from branch or other names, they do eventually go away).
- Branch names *move*.  Branch names let us, and Git, find commits.  They move in predictable ways, by *adding* commits to the branch.  Some operations, such as `git rebase` or `git reset`, move them in big sudden ways and maybe in ways that are "less natural", not just advancing to incorporate more commits.
- `git rebase` is about *copying* commits.  We make new-and-improved copies, wth different hash IDs, and make a branch name point to the last *copied* commit.  The originals can't be changed, but if you move a branch *name*, anyone who didn't save the hash IDs of the originals won't be able to *find* the originals.
- `git fetch` is about two things: *getting new commits from another Git* and *updating remote-tracking names like `origin/master` based on what is in that other Git*.  If we *did* get new commits, all we have to remember them at this point is these remote-tracking names, so we generally need a second command.
- `git pull` is meant to be convenient: it runs `git fetch`, then it runs a second command, usually `git merge`.
- Sometimes, this is *not* convenient.  I actually find that it's inconvenient more often than it is convenient.  In that case, just *don't use it*.

Answer (score -1):

try interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i e3f8704
```

e3f8704 is your commit hash code.

Comment: Why does the rebase need to be interactive?

Comment: [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---interactive)